# set recurring column names in R data frame

Tags: r

I have 2 data frames - df "A" has unique column names; and df "B" has the group into which these unique column names from "A" belong to.
For example :

```
> A
 ID1 ID2 ID3 ID4 ID5 ID6 
1 0.5 0.2 0.0 0.6 0.8 0.2 
2 0.1 0.3 0.1 0.4 0.0 0.4 
3 1.2 1.1 1.4 1.5 1.9 1.3 
4 1.1 1.3 1.5 1.9 1.0 1.1 

> B
ID   Group 
ID1  Grp1
ID2  Grp2
ID3  Grp1
ID4  Grp1
ID5  Grp2
ID6  Grp2
```

I am trying to convert the column names of "A" such that they reflect the group names, and not the unique IDs. However , when I do this conversion , R automatically add .1, .2,.. suffix to the column names which is hindering in my downstream analyses.

Here is my code :

```
names = colnames(A)
colnames(A) <- as.character(B$Group[match(colnames(A),B$ID)])
counts = table(colnames(A))
to_keep = names(counts)[counts >= 1]
pData <- B[B$Group %in% to_keep,]
to_keep = which(colnames(A) %in% to_keep)   
A <- A[,to_keep]
names <- names[to_keep]
```

Let me know how I can fix this !

Thanks !

EDIT : Thank you all for your help! I managed to get non-unique column names with your help. I will explain my use case here so maybe then you might understand why I want to do this this way.

I have a df "A" such that some columns belong to grp1 and some belong to grp2 .
I want to be able to generate a training set for training an algorithm. This set is created by randomly taking some of these groups and mixing them up.
The code for that is like so:

```
names(A) <- B$Group[match(names(A), B$ID)]
counts = table(colnames(A))
training <- as.numeric(unlist(sapply(unique(colnames(A)), function(x) {
  sample(which(colnames(A) %in% x), counts[x]/2) })))
```

Any alternative method is welcome for this use case.

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this?

```
names(A) = setNames(B$Group, B$ID)[names(A)]
```

This is based on the assumption that you want the column in A called "ID1" to become called "Grp1" and so on.

I will keep this around because it is a different approach to the other answer, but I too agree having non-unique names is not a good practice.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `match` :

```
names(A) <- B$Group[match(names(A), B$ID)]
A
#  Grp1 Grp2 Grp1 Grp1 Grp2 Grp2
#1  0.5  0.2  0.0  0.6  0.8  0.2
#2  0.1  0.3  0.1  0.4  0.0  0.4
#3  1.2  1.1  1.4  1.5  1.9  1.3
#4  1.1  1.3  1.5  1.9  1.0  1.1
```

However, it is not a good practice to have duplicate column names. You can add some prefix/suffix to distinguish the column names. Maybe append the original column names to group name?

```
names(A) <- paste(B$Group[match(names(A), B$ID)], names(A), sep = '_')
A

#  Grp1_ID1 Grp2_ID2 Grp1_ID3 Grp1_ID4 Grp2_ID5 Grp2_ID6
#1      0.5      0.2      0.0      0.6      0.8      0.2
#2      0.1      0.3      0.1      0.4      0.0      0.4
#3      1.2      1.1      1.4      1.5      1.9      1.3
#4      1.1      1.3      1.5      1.9      1.0      1.1
```

Answer (score 0):

We can also use

```
library(dplyr)
A <- A %>% 
  rename_at(vars(B$ID), ~ make.unique(B$Group))
```

-output

```
A
# Grp1 Grp2 Grp1.1 Grp1.2 Grp2.1 Grp2.2
#1  0.5  0.2    0.0    0.6    0.8    0.2
#2  0.1  0.3    0.1    0.4    0.0    0.4
#3  1.2  1.1    1.4    1.5    1.9    1.3
#4  1.1  1.3    1.5    1.9    1.0    1.1
```